# Query not updating after AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I am using a call to AJAX to update a value in a table which Im then using in a query locate data in the table for output. The data is updating in the table as required, but not in query output after the AJAX updates the table.

Here is my work:

**AJAX on index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".accept").click(function(){
var element = $(this);
var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
var info = 'id=' + del_id;

 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "accept.php",
   data: info,
   success: function(){}

});
  $(this).parents(".show").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
  .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");

});
});
</script>
```

It sends data to accept.php, which uses the data to update the table:

**accept.php**

```
include('db.php');
$id = $_POST['id'] ;
$name = $_POST['order_id'] ;
$sql = "UPDATE mgap_ska SET mgap_status = '1' WHERE mgap_ska_id = '".$id."' AND mgap_ska_report_category = '".$name."';"; 
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); 

$stmt->execute(array(
':id' => '$id',
':name' => '$name'
));
```

and then I query the table for the updated info:

```
"SELECT SUM(mgap_ska_growth) AS total FROM mgap_ska WHERE mgap_status = 1 ";
```

'mgap_ska_growth' is a column full of dollar values and all related 'mgap_status' values are set to '0' by default. The AJAX updates a row value from '0' to '1' and the query locates all values with mgap_status of '1' and SUMs there totals.

The SUM is working, but only once upon entering the site. The query output doesn't update after the AJAX runs even though the values in the table are uodating as require.

What am I missing?

Comment: There is something wrong with `info = 'id=' + del_id`, and then in server side you called `$_POST['order_id']`... !!! you just posted the `id`...

Answer (score 1):

You  didn't set  `order_id` in javascript.

```
$(function() {
$(".accept").click(function(){
var element = $(this);
var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
var order_id  = //something collect order_id
var info = 'id=' + del_id + '&order_id=' + /*order_id value*/;

 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "accept.php",
   data: info,
   success: function(){}

});
  $(this).parents(".show").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
  .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");

});
});
```

because you used `AND` in your query and you didn't set **`$_POST['order_id']`**, and then  **`$name`**, your query will always return false...

and I think you should recheck this part:

```
$sql = "UPDATE mgap_ska SET mgap_status = '1' WHERE mgap_ska_id = '".$id."' AND mgap_ska_report_category = '".$name."';"; 
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); 

$stmt->execute(array(
':id' => '$id',
':name' => '$name'
));
```

***`try this type :`***

```
$sql = "UPDATE mgap_ska SET mgap_status = '1' WHERE mgap_ska_id = :id AND mgap_ska_report_category = :name;"; 
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); 

$stmt->execute(array(
':id' => $id,
':name' => $name
));
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the main issue. Now is there something Ive left out that would cause the AJAX to only run one time per page?On the first row it functions as needed; one the second row the update doesn't occur.

Comment: @TechnoCripple As much as I can find out without have a look to your HTML structure is that, you left success function `empty`. I'll update the answer...

Comment: Im not using AJAX to output an element area, I need the variables from the query to update each time the AJAX is used. They're only updating on the first call.